# Given two positions, and a list of all positions, find quickest path

Tags: language-agnostic, path-finding

I have two points `(x1, y1)` & `(x2, y2)`, and a list of all possible positions that can be traversed across with format `(x, y)`, how would I find/estimate the quickest path between the two values.

I am implementing this in Java, but the language doesn't matter much.

---

Some limitations & additional info around the question:

- The values of `x1` & `x2` will be never the same, unless `y1 = y2`, this is because these positions are always located on the *edge* of a box.
- There may not always be a path between `(x1, y1)` & `(x2, y2)` (for when checking for continuity between the paths
- Not all possible points will be connected to either `(x1, y1)` or `(x2, y2)`
- Shortest path isn't required but would be handy to know
- Would be happy with simply some hints about what direction to take or algorithms to look into
- Travel can happen via a diagonal (`(x, y)` & `(x + 1, y + 1)` are considered neighbours)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I was looking for is to use [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) as a search algorithm, this finds the shortest path between two points given a map of all the nodes.